# Android Recyclerview, loading same images from URl using Glide

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am able to retrieve text data successfully from firebase, but i got some difficulty in doing the same for images. I am using a recycler view and below is my recycler adapter:

```
private void updateList() {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserInformation, listOnlineViewHolder>(
            UserInformation.class,
            R.layout.user_layout,
            listOnlineViewHolder.class,
            counterRef
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(listOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final UserInformation model, int position) {

            Glide.with(ListOnline.this)
                    .load(uPictureUrl)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(viewHolder.ivProfilePic);



            viewHolder.txName.setText(model.getFullName());
            viewHolder.txNumber.setText(model.getPhoneNo());

            //Implement item click of recycler view
            viewHolder.itemClickListenener = new ItemClickListenener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListOnline.this, "On Click action ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // If model is current user not set click event
                    if(!model.getFirebaseUID().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                    {
                        Intent map = new Intent(ListOnline.this, MapTracking.class );
                        map.putExtra("name", model.getFullName());
                        map.putExtra("lat", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                        map.putExtra("lan", mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                        startActivity(map);
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listOnline.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Please help me i am stuck on this problem

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to find problem .add the whole code of Adapter

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Note: **image_url** is url of image.Before loading it try it in browser whether you can see the image.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Not working still the same problem showing same user image on every user list

Comment: post your iamge url